# Changing the quality of the transient process in a nonlinear system (in Mathematica)

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, dynamics, nonlinear-control, adaptive-control

I urgently need advice and help.

I have a system of differential equations like this:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} = y[t] \cdot \alpha \cdot sin(\omega t) + \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha \cdot sin(\omega t))
   \\ \frac{dy}{dt} + h \cdot y(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-(x[t] - 2)^2}) \end{cases}$

Parameters: $\alpha = 0.3, h = 1, \omega = 2 \pi 0.5, x(0)=1/4, y(0)=0$

It corresponds to the following structural scheme:

[image]

The code that simulates such a system is shown below:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {\[Alpha]1 = 0.3, h1 = 1, \[Omega]1 = 2 Pi 0.5}

extr = Exp[-(x[t] - 2)^2]

sys = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
    y[t] \[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t] + 
     D[\[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t], t], 
   y'[t] + h1 y[t] == D[extr, t], x[0] == 1/4, y[0] == 0}, 
  x, {t, 0, 500}]
```

The numerical solution is presented below:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

**It can be seen that the transition process is a transition from the initial point to the final one with a certain character.**

**I need to change this character i.e. make the transition from one point to another *exponentially*.**
Like this:

[image]

What are the ways to solve this problem? What to do, add a regulator or manipulate the system of differential equations?

Please help me!

Comment: what is  hpf1[t]?

Comment: I'm sorry. It is y(t)

Comment: Well, generally you are trying to control a nonlinear system ? Is this the case or not ? You have a nonlinear system and you want to force certain behaviour to its output, right ?

Comment: @Teo Protoulis, Yes, you are absolutely right. It is necessary to introduce something into the system (a link or an additional control signal) that provides a given transient process (in this case, exponential). Those. endow the system with adaptive properties.

Comment: Well, then you have to introduce some design specifications first of all and then choose which control scheme for nonlinear systems is appropriate to design for this specific system. Is the ES Controller block fixed or have you designed it ?

Comment: 1. ES Controller block - a method known in the literature for measuring the gradient of a function.? 
2. Let's take as a starting point the problem of providing an exponential transient with a time constant T = 1 for simplicity. As for the choice of a suitable scheme, I do not know any scheme suitable for this task at all.

Comment: @Teo Protoulis, what do you think?

Comment: If you don't know any scheme that could be a possible choice, I wonder how you would go about designing a controller for this system ? From my perspective your desired behaviour could be the output of a linear system (first or second order) which tracks a step input of certain amplitude. But designing a controller that can force your nonlinear system to follow the output of the linear system, which I mentioned as an example, isn't an easy task at all. What's your background regarding these topics ?

Comment: @Teo Protoulis, My experience is limited to the development of the simplest adaptive systems, where adaptation is implemented by introducing an additional control signal.

Comment: in this case, it is necessary to set such a law of variation of the gradient of the function in order to provide an exponential process, but at the same time observe the starting and ending points

Comment: I mean, don't you think it would be better to first grasp the required theoretical background and then proceed to more complicated tasks ?

Comment: @Teo Protoulis, I have a small theoretical base, but, as it turned out, there are no tools in it to solve such a problem